# python pandas dataframe calculation

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with two numeric columns **item_cnt_day** and **item_price**.
I want to create a new column called **rev** in my dataframe which is calculated by (**item_cnt_day * item_price**). However, I want to add the condition **rev = item_cnt_day * item_price** only if **item_cnt_day** is larger or equal to 0, otherwise, rev = 0. Could you help me write the code for this condition when creating new column **rev**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use loc accessor with boolean masking:

```
df['rev']=0
df.loc[df['item_cnt_day'].ge(0),'rev']=df['item_cnt_day'].mul(df['item_price'])
```

OR

You can use `where()`:

```
df['rev']=df['item_cnt_day'].mul(df['item_price']).where(df['item_cnt_day'].ge(0),0)
#df['item_cnt_day'].mul(df['item_price']).mask(df['item_cnt_day'].lt(0),0)
```

OR

via `np.where()`:

```
import numpy as np
df['rev']=np.where(df['item_cnt_day'].ge(0),df['item_cnt_day'].mul(df['item_price']),0)
```